# Collect and Display Hadoop MapReduce resutls in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, hadoop

Beginner questions.  I read this article about Hadoop/MapReduce

http://www.amazedsaint.com/2012/06/analyzing-some-big-data-using-c-azure.html

I get the idea of hadoop and what is map and what is reduce.

The thing for me is, if my application sits on top of a hadoop cluster

1) No need for database anymore?

2) How do I get my data into hadoop in the first place from my ASP.NET MVC application? Say it's Stackoverflow (which is coded in MVC). After I post this question, how can this question along with the title, body, tags get into hadoop?

3) In the above article, it collects data about "namespaces" used on Stakoverflow and how many times they were used.

If this site stackoverflow wants to display the result data from mapreducer in real time, how do you do that?

Sorry for the rookie questions. I'm just trying to get a clear pictures here one piece at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) That would depend on the application. Most likely you still need database for user management, etc.

2) If you are using Amazon EMR, you'd place the inputs into S3 using [.NET API](http://aws.amazon.com/net/) (or some other way) and get the results out the same way. You could also monitor your EMR account via API, fairly straight-forward.

3) Hadoop is not really a real-time environment, more of a batch system. You could simulate 
realtime by continuous processing of incoming data, however it's still not true real-time.

I'd recommend taking a look at [Amazon EMR .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/net/) docs and pick up a good book on Hadoop (such as [Hadoop in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290238) to understand the stack and concepts and Hive (such as [Programming Hive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009D76316))

Also, you can, of course, mix the environments for what they are best at; for example, use Azure Websites and SQLAzure for your .NET app and Amazon EMR for hadoop/hive. No need to park everything in one place, considering cost models.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank Kgu87 for the book suggestion. Going to get it this weekend. Also I will look into Amazon EMR as suggested. I wonder how does Twitter do it? They use Lucene for search, I get it... but how do they come up with their stats so quickly baffles me.

Comment: Check out the company called Backtype (backtype.com) recently acquired by Twitter and Nathan Marz's slideshare presentation on how they did it - http://www.slideshare.net/nathanmarz/the-secrets-of-building-realtime-big-data-systems . In a nutshell - incremental, micro-batch. Should give you a general idea :)

Comment: Excellent @kgu87. Thanks once again!